# RubyCritic : How to remove FeatureEnvy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, optimization

See Attachment

[image]

I have migration file that having 15 line of code.
This 15 lines of code getting **3 smells**.

1. TooManyStatement
2. UncommunicativeVariableName
3. FeatureEnvy

I'm not able to understand How can i write this code to remove this errors?

So Please help me for this.

Comment: and the code itself ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually DSL methods wouldn't pass style checks so it's a common thing to exclude these files. Since `FeatureEnvy` should be a part of [reek](https://github.com/troessner/reek) you should take a look at `exclude_paths` option in configuration example: https://github.com/troessner/reek#configuration-options